# Get url configuration in django 404 pages when Mezzanine is installed

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm working with mezzanine for a django project, and I can't figure out how to turn back on the DEBUG=True url configuration output that django usually produces on 404 pages.

With mezzanine installed, even with DEBUG=True, all I ever get is a blank 404 page.

Steps tried without success:

- Googling around for "mezzanine 404 url" and various implementations
- Skimming Mezzanine documentation
- Disabling the custom mezzanine 404 handler

Any ideas on how to get the standard django url report back?

Thanks

Comment: Umm, what happens when you set `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: It doesn't show when DEBUG=True

Comment: So, you are saying that when you set `DEBUG=True`, restart the server, and visit a URL that is not mapped to any view, you are not getting the django 404 page?

Comment: When Mezzanine is installed, when DEBUG=True, when you visit a URL that is not mapped, you get a different 404 page than the one that django normally ships with -- the mezzanine 404 page does not show the URL config.  Restarting the server does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Mezzanine contains a "catch all" urlpattern for pages. That is, the pattern for Mezzanine pages could be *anything* - example.com/foo, example.com/foo/bar, etc. So what you get is a standard 404 error.

What you're looking for is the error that occurs when *no* urlpattern matches the url requested. This can't actually occur with Mezzanine, since its patterns can match any url.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  Is there an advantage to using a catch-all url instead of a fallback middleware like flatpages uses?